# Unable to get list from xml using xPathNavigator

Tags: c#, xml, list, xpathnavigator

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (XPathNavigator node in nav.Select("configuration/company/work/worktime"))
            {
                string day = getAttribute(node, "day");
                string time = getAttribute(node, "time");
                string worktype = ?? // how to get worktype attribute valuefrom parent node 
              list.Add(day,time,worktype); // add to list 
            }

 </configuration>
      <company>
        <work worktype="homeWork">
            <worktime day="30" time="10:28"></worktime>
            <worktime day="25" time="10:50"></worktime>
         </work>
        <work worktype="officeWork">
            <worktime day="12" time="09:28"></worktime>
            <worktime day="15" time="12:28"></worktime>
        </work>
      </company>
    </configuration>


need output as :
list[0] = homeWork,30,10:28
list[1] = homeWork,25,10:50
list[2] = officeWork,12,09:28
list[3] = officeWork,15,12:28
```

I am trying to get the list from XML but failed to get output like given above (using xpath navigator, how can I access parent node to get worktype attribute, and other remaining inner node attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using LINQ to XML over XPath, but if you must use `XPathNavigator` then you need to iterate each `work` element followed by each of its `worktime` child elements.  This way you can use the `worktype` from the parent context:

```
foreach (XPathNavigator work in nav.Select("configuration/company/work"))
{
    var workType = work.GetAttribute("worktype", string.Empty);

    foreach (XPathNavigator worktime in work.Select("worktime"))
    {
        var day = worktime.GetAttribute("day", string.Empty);
        var time = worktime.GetAttribute("time", string.Empty);

        list.Add($"{workType}, {day}, {time}");
    }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kSHZgC) for a working demo.

Comment: cool its working , can you explain me why "string.Empty" has been taken

Comment: A name in XML is made of two parts: a namespace and a local name. `string.Empty` or `""` is used here because the names in your XML do not have a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested loop. Initially retrieve the work nodes with `configuration/company/work`. Retrieve the worktype attribute and store in a variable. Then loop through the child worktype nodes and add a string to the list for each one

Comment: tried the same but when i do foreach loop for configuration/company/work/worktime it adds double entry for same worktype, means above are 2 records for homeWork - i am getting 4 records for it which inclueds its 2 own and another 2 records of officeWork

Answer (score 0):

Use Net Library enhanced xml (linq xml)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants("work").Select(x => new {
                worktype = (string)x.Attribute("worktype"),
                worktime = x.Elements("worktime").Select(y => new {
                    day = (int)y.Attribute("day"),
                    time = (DateTime)y.Attribute("time")
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks its working but i have to do it with xPathNavigator

Comment: I do not like using 3rd party dlls which can contain viruses.

Comment: @jdweng yeah, that `System.Xml.dll` from Microsoft is often known to ship with viruses ;)